# CSS Less - Get height property of current class

Tags: css, class, less

I've got this:

```
.class {
  height:10px; 
  padding:2px; 
  box-sizing:border-box;
}

.class .subclass {
  height:100%; 
  line-height:???;
}
```

As you can see `class` has a fixed height but `subclass` has a relative percent height. This height, despite it has value `100%`, isn't equal to parent's height because it's affected by parent's `padding` property. What I need is to set `line-height` property equal to `height` property in order to center the text vertically.

**The question:**
How can I get the current class (the class we are setting `line-height` property) height with LESS?

I know I can set variables and then do a calc, this way:

```
@class-height:10px;
@class-padding:2px;
@subclass-height:calc(@class-height - @class-padding * 2); //*2 because of Top & bottom padding

.class {
  height:@class-height; 
  padding:@class-padding; 
  box-sizing:border-box;
}

.class .subclass {
  height:@subclass-height; 
  line-height:@subclass-height;
}
```

But I want to know if is there a simple way to achieve this without calculations and the setting of fixed variables.

Comment: [This](https://jsfiddle.net/pt366e9k/) is one possible method to achieve vertical centering without using `line-height`. I am not aware of any drawbacks and I think it might be useful for you. (*I had changed the `height` of the parent just to show how the text stays centered even when parent's height changes.*)

Answer (score 2):

If the parent height is a fixed number you can use absolute positioning.

```
.parent{
  height: 100px; 
  background-color: tomato; 
  width: 100%; 
}

.child{
  position: relative; 
  left: 0; 
  right: 0; 
  margin: 0 auto; 
  top: 50%; 
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  text-align: center; 
}
```

The other option is to take advantage of vertical-align property for `table` so you can write your css like this.

```
.parent{
  height: 100px; 
  background-color: tomato; 
  width: 100%; 
  display: table;
  text-align: center; 
}

.child{
  display: table-cell;
  margin: 0 auto; 
  text-align: center; 
  vertical-align: middle; 
}
```

Comment: Those are good ways to do it! By the way, I'm still interested in the option with LESS. Thanks ;)